# Как избавиться от обновленной иконки Qt Creator

Tags: qtcreator, ide, дизайн, icon

У меня сложилось субъективное мнение, что новая иконка Qt Creator была нарисована в Paint. Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли ее откатить до старой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень подробное [руководство](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2019/06/22/qt-yet-another-new-icon/) для macOS. Образцы иконок вменяемого вида под разный размер можно подцепить [тут](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/releases/tag/v4.0.0), после распаковки архива с сурсами чекните данный путь (для мака не забудьте перед перетаскиванием как в руководстве преобразовать [*.png в *.icns](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns)):

> qt-creator-4.0.0/src/app/qtcreator.xcassets/qtcreator.appiconset

Можно добавить, что на Windows иконка приложения так же может быть изменена в свойствах ярлыка меню пуск (*.png преобразуем в *.ico этим [конвертером](https://image.online-convert.com/ru/convert-to-ico)). Для дистрибутивов Linux могу посоветовать попробовать данное [руководство](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) для оболочки рабочего стола Gnome: возможно ошибаюсь, но вроде бы, тот же стандарт из коробки поддерживают все остальные оболочки.